# List private AMIs sorted by time with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to get **describe-images** to return list of AMIs sorted by time?
Right now it seems to sort them randomly (whereas the AWS Console shows me sorted by time each time I log in -- probably because I clicked the time column to sort it by that once and this preference is being persisted).

I've searched the doc for sorting (i.e., "sort", "order", ..)  and cannot seem to find it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting feature is generic to the CLI, not specific to the describe-instances command.

You can accomplish this using jmespath querying.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

http://jmespath.org/specification.html#func-sort-by